# Using Timer To Schedule Notifications Triggering

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, nstimer

I am trying to schedule a Timer to fire at a specific date and time, based on what the user selects in UIDatePicker. When the Timer fires, I want to set up a repeating notification (UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger) every 60 seconds. The Timer seems to fire and the console shows the notification being added without error, but I never receive a notification. What am I doing wrong?

```
@IBAction func triggerNotification(_ sender: Any) {
    if (reminderText.text!.count > 0)
    {
        let timer = Timer(fireAt: datePicker.date, interval: 0, target: self, selector: #selector(setUpReminder), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        reminderText.text = ""
    }
}
@objc func setUpReminder()
{
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    let identifier = reminderText.text!
    content.title = "Your Reminder"
    content.body = identifier
    content.badge = 1
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 60.0, repeats: true)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request){
        (error) in
        if error != nil
        {
            print("here error in setting up notification")
            print(error!)
        } else
        {
            print("notification scheduled")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func sendNotification(){

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Timer"
    content.body = "30 Seconds"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 0.001, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "timer.request", content: content, trigger: trigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { (error) in
        if let error = error{
            print("Error posting notification:\(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else{
            print("notification scheduled")
        }
    }
}


@objc func setUpReminder()
{
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
        options: [.alert,.sound])
    {(granted, error) in

       self.sendNotification()
   }
}
```

> this is working code you were just assigning wrong timeinterval :)

Comment: Are you saying that the timerInterval in UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger was off? It was working when I was testing without using Timer. I think Timer may be the issue

Comment: @JDub i have use the same timer code which is in ur question except datePicker.date was my current Date()